# How to deserialize splitted json data

Tags: python, json, deserialization

I stream data via Server Send Event and get about `500.000 datasets` but instead of getting one json I get this  (example of 2 of the 500.000 datasets)(this is how it looks like opening it in gedit, all question marks are \" and all new lines are \n):

```
data:{\"data\":[\"Kendrick\",\"Lamar\"]}\n\ndata:{\"data\":[\"David\",\"Bowie\"]}\n\n
... -
```

My goal is to get this into a database. I actually thought I put this into a dictionary and afterwards create a pandas dataframe from here on I should be able to get it into a database. But this ends up to be quite cumbersome. I ended up with something like this:

```
c1 = data_json[1:-1]
c2 = c1.replace('{data:{', '{\"data\":{')
c3 = c2.replace('}data:{', ', ')
c4 = '{' + c3 + '}'
```

but even here I have some problems since I have to add /n/n for the new lines. But  as soon as I change `c3` to `c2.replace('}\n\ndata:{', ', ')` I get `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`. Coming from .NET I could handle this quite easy with a deserializer and I am wondering if there is a similar way to deserialize the data. 
I get the data via sseclient and would be able to store them as bytes instead of string, if this would help, just fyi.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juggling with replaces is of course a convoluted path - 
the language does have the parsers for this kind of escaping built in - 
the simpler of which would be passing the string that contains JSON through an `eval` call. But eval is seldom needed and should be avoided in most cases as "not elegant" - if not outright unsafe (but being unsafe actually just applies when you have no control over the input data - and even them, `ast.literal_eval` instead of plain `eval` can mitigate that). Anyway, there are other problems with the format that will prevent eval to work outright - the missing quotes of the outmost `data:`, for example.

Random rants apart,  if your file content is actually:

```
data:{\"data\":[\"Kendrick\",\"Lamar\"]}\n\ndata:{\"data\":[\"David\",\"Bowie\"]}\n\n
```

It has two problems: "under-quoting' of the outmost `data` and an 
"over-scaping" of the inner-data.

On an interactive Python session, using the "raw string" marker I can input your example line as it will be read from a file:

```
In [263]: a = r"""data:{\"data\":[\"Kendrick\",\"Lamar\"]}\n\ndata:{\"data\":[\"David\",\"Bowie\"]}\n\n"""                                             

In [264]: print(a)                                                                                                                                     
data:{\"data\":[\"Kendrick\",\"Lamar\"]}\n\ndata:{\"data\":[\"David\",\"Bowie\"]}\n\n
```

So, on to remove one level of backslashes - Python have an "unicode_escape" text encoding, but it only works from bytes-objects. We then resort to the "latin1" encoding, as it provides a byte-for-byte conversion of the unicode literal in "a" to bytes, and then apply an unicode_escape to remove the "\" :

```
In [266]: b = a.encode("latin1").decode("unicode_escape")  

In [267]: print(b, "\n", repr(b))                                                                                                                      
data:{"data":["Kendrick","Lamar"]}

data:{"data":["David","Bowie"]}


 'data:{"data":["Kendrick","Lamar"]}\n\ndata:{"data":["David","Bowie"]}\n\n'
```

now it is easy to parse: 
We split the resulting string at "\n\n" and have one list with one record
(those you are calling "dataset") per element. Then we resort to string
manipulation to get rid of the starting `"data:"` and finally, `json.load` can work on the remaining part.

so:

```
import json

raw_data = open("mystrangefile.pseudo_json").read()
data = data.encode("latin1").decode("unicode_escape")
records = [json.loads(record.split(":", 1)[-1]) for record in data.split("\n\n")]
```

And "records" now should contain well behaved Python objects dictionaries, you can put in a database. (Unless Pandas can provide automatic mapping of the columns to a databas, it seems to be an uneeded step - a  raw `connection.executemany(""" INSERT ...""", records)` with a  proper open DB connection should suffice.

Also, on a sidenote you mentioned that you could handle this easily with a .NET deserializer:  that is only if your files are not as broken as you have shown us - no possible standard serializer could know how to handle such an specific data format out of the box. But, if you actually is that  more proeficient in another language/technology to do that, you could resort to write just a converter from the broken input to a properly encoded file, and use that as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if I understood the format in which you get the string correctly, so please correct me if I'm wrong here:

`data_json = 'data:{\\"data\\":[\\"Kendrick\\",\\"Lamar\\"]}\\n\\ndata:{\\"data\\":[\\"David\\",\\"Bowie\\"]}\\n\\n'`

Your first line seems to strip the first and last character, which I don't see. Are there any additional characters you are stripping away here?

The two following substring replacements seem to have no effect as the substrings are not present in the initial string (if I got it correctly in the first place).

And finally in the last line you are wrapping your result with `{` and `}` which is not correct for lists in json. It should be `[...]`

I can't really tell why you would get a SIGKILL here, though. It does not throw any errors for me, it just does not do what you want it to do. Maybe you're running out of memory with all the 500k examples?

However, this would be a working solution (again, given that I got the initial string correctly):

```
c1 = data_json.replace('\\n\\n', '')  # removing escaped newlines
c2 = c1.replace('data:', ',') # replacing the additional 'data:' with json delimiter ','
c3 = c2.replace('\\', '') # removing artificial escapes
c4 = c3[1:-1] # removing leading ',' (introduced in c2) and trailing newline
c5 = '[' + c4 + ']' # wrapping as list
```

Now you should be able to `json.loads(c5)` or whatever you need to do with that string.